# Getting title and meta tags from external website

Tags: php, curl, title, meta-tags

I want to try figure out how to get the

```
<title>A common title</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Keywords blabla" />
<meta name="description" content="This is the description" />
```

Even though if it's arranged in any order, I've heard of the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser but I don't really want to use it. Is it possible for a solution except using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

`preg_match` will not be able to do it if it's invalid HTML?

Can cURL do something like this with preg_match?

Facebook does something like this but it's properly used by using:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Description blabla" />
```

I want something like this so that it is possible when someone posts a link, it should retrieve the title and the meta tags. If there are no meta tags, then it it ignored or the user can set it themselves (but I'll do that later on myself).

Answer (score 181, accepted):

This is the way it should be:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://example.com/");

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";
```

Comment: Two years later and still works flawlessly, changed the attributes to get the `og:` tags related with OpenGraph and works perfectly well

Comment: Awesome! Thanks shamittomar. Add `strtolower` around `$meta->getAttribute()`!! Sometimes they have a capital at the front

Comment: @shamittomar would you mind showing an example on codepad or pastebin of how to modify this code when the URL's are in an array.

Comment: Works great but in my case it did not work for few URLs, after debugging i found that, `$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');` returns length of results and whenever title is missing it threw a warning.  So simply replace next line i.e. `$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;` by `if ($nodes->length>0) {
   $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  }`

Comment: why curl and not just file_get_contents ?

Comment: This is one of the better answers to doing this. I made you method into a small composer package, which can be found on: https://github.com/diversen/get-meta-tags This also has better options for setting timeout and selecting which tags to fetch.

Comment: can I get og:image url using this?

Comment: Doesnt usually work. Trying it on `https://www.stackoverflow.com` for example. Returns `Document Moved` whereas this resolves fine in a browser.

Comment: Still works in 2019 for `og:` related social media tags.  My use case is a custom wordpress blog template that needed to look at pages `og:description` in order to get a proper blog excerpt.

Comment: See this answer to render emojis on `->loadHTML`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/1287812

Comment: Hey everbody, do you have any idea why this example isn't working with a public fan page of facebook? I can't read the meta tags from any facebook page like  https://www.facebook.com/MeineNanny when I check with https://metatags.io/ i can see the meta description, when I try to read with php I can't get them! Ideas?

Answer (score 42):

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```

Comment: this doesn't provide the page title though

Comment: ^because it is a function related to meta tag, how on earth will it return something-it isn't concerned with.

Comment: Hey everbody, do you have any idea why this example isn't working with a public fan page of facebook? I can't read the meta tags from any facebook page. Example: https://www.facebook.com/MeineNanny when I check with https://metatags.io/ i can see the meta description, when I try to read with php I can't get them! Ideas?

Answer (score 11):

`get_meta_tags` will help you with all but the title. To get the title just use a regex.

```
$url = 'http://some.url.com';
preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/siU", file_get_contents($url), $matches);
$title = $matches[1];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

`get_meta_tags` did not work with title.

Only meta tags with name attributes like

```
<meta name="description" content="the description">
```

will be parsed.

Answer (score 6):

Php's native function:
get_meta_tags()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Answer (score 6):

**Shouldnt we be using OG?**

The chosen answer is good but doesn't work when a site is **redirected** (very common!), and doesn't return **OG tags**, which are [the new industry standard](http://ogp.me/). Here's a little function which is a bit more usable in 2018. It tries to get OG tags and falls back to meta tags if it cant them:

```
function getSiteOG( $url, $specificTags=0 ){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $res['title'] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $m){
        $tag = $m->getAttribute('name') ?: $m->getAttribute('property');
        if(in_array($tag,['description','keywords']) || strpos($tag,'og:')===0) $res[str_replace('og:','',$tag)] = $m->getAttribute('content');
    }
    return $specificTags? array_intersect_key( $res, array_flip($specificTags) ) : $res;
}
```

How to use it:

```
/////////////
//SAMPLE USAGE:
print_r(getSiteOG("http://www.stackoverflow.com")); //note the incorrect url

/////////////
//OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [title] => Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
    [description] => Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, shareâ âtheir programming âknowledge, and build their careers.
    [type] => website
    [url] => https://stackoverflow.com/
    [site_name] => Stack Overflow
    [image] => https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the built in php function get_meta_tags() requires the name parameter, and certain sites, such as twitter leave that off in favor of the property attribute.  This function, using a mix of regex and dom document, will return a keyed array of metatags from a webpage.  It checks for the name parameter, then the property parameter.  This has been tested on instragram, pinterest and twitter.

```
/**
 * Extract metatags from a webpage
 */
function extract_tags_from_url($url) {
  $tags = array();

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

  $contents = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  if (empty($contents)) {
    return $tags;
  }

  if (preg_match_all('/<meta([^>]+)content="([^>]+)>/', $contents, $matches)) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . implode($matches[0]));
    $tags = array();
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $metaTag) {
      if($metaTag->getAttribute('name') != "") {
        $tags[$metaTag->getAttribute('name')] = $metaTag->getAttribute('content');
      }
      elseif ($metaTag->getAttribute('property') != "") {
        $tags[$metaTag->getAttribute('property')] = $metaTag->getAttribute('content');
      }
    }
  }

  return $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple function to understand how to retrieve og:tags, title and description, adapt this for yourself

```
function read_og_tags_as_json($url){


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $HTML_DOCUMENT = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($HTML_DOCUMENT);

    // fecth <title>
    $res['title'] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // fetch og:tags
    foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $m ){

          // if had property
          if( $m->getAttribute('property') ){

              $prop = $m->getAttribute('property');

              // here search only og:tags
              if( preg_match("/og:/i", $prop) ){

                  // get results on an array -> nice for templating
                  $res['og_tags'][] =
                  array( 'property' => $m->getAttribute('property'),
                          'content' => $m->getAttribute('content') );
              }

          }
          // end if had property

          // fetch <meta name="description" ... >
          if( $m->getAttribute('name') == 'description' ){

            $res['description'] = $m->getAttribute('content');

          }


    }
    // end foreach

    // render JSON
    echo json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT |
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

}
```

Return for this page (may have more infos) :

```
{
    "title": "php - Getting title and meta tags from external website - Stack Overflow",
    "og_tags": [
        {
            "property": "og:type",
            "content": "website"
        },
        {
            "property": "og:url",
            "content": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website"
        },
        {
            "property": "og:site_name",
            "content": "Stack Overflow"
        },
        {
            "property": "og:image",
            "content": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"
        },
        {
            "property": "og:title",
            "content": "Getting title and meta tags from external website"
        },
        {
            "property": "og:description",
            "content": "I want to try figure out how to get the\n\n&lt;title&gt;A common title&lt;/title&gt;\n&lt;meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Keywords blabla\" /&gt;\n&lt;meta name=\"description\" content=\"This is the descript..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use the following to decode emojis when rendering JSON: `$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($HTML_DOCUMENT, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));`

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to bite the bullet use the DOM Parser - it's the 'right way' to do it. In the long run it'll save you more time than it takes to learn how. Parsing HTML with Regex is known to be unreliable and intolerant of special cases.

Comment: +1, with the addition that if you just use the built-in DOM extension instead of Simple HTML DOM Parser you are probably a _lot_ faster, and you don't clutter code with a 3rd party library (although, you add a requirement to your server-environment, i.e. DOM enabled, which it is by default).

Answer (score 3):

We use **Apache Tika** via php (command line utility) with -j for json :

http://tika.apache.org/

```
<?php
    shell_exec( 'java -jar tika-app-1.4.jar -j http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying' );
?>
```

This is a sample **output** from a random guardian article :

```
{
   "Content-Encoding":"UTF-8",
   "Content-Length":205599,
   "Content-Type":"text/html; charset\u003dUTF-8",
   "DC.date.issued":"2013-07-21",
   "X-UA-Compatible":"IE\u003dEdge,chrome\u003d1",
   "application-name":"The Guardian",
   "article:author":"http://www.guardian.co.uk/profile/nicholaswatt",
   "article:modified_time":"2013-07-21T22:42:21+01:00",
   "article:published_time":"2013-07-21T22:00:03+01:00",
   "article:section":"Politics",
   "article:tag":[
      "Lynton Crosby",
      "Health policy",
      "NHS",
      "Health",
      "Healthcare industry",
      "Society",
      "Public services policy",
      "Lobbying",
      "Conservatives",
      "David Cameron",
      "Politics",
      "UK news",
      "Business"
   ],
   "content-id":"/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "dc:title":"Tory strategist Lynton Crosby in new lobbying row | Politics | The Guardian",
   "description":"Exclusive: Firm he founded, Crosby Textor, advised private healthcare providers how to exploit NHS \u0027failings\u0027",
   "fb:app_id":180444840287,
   "keywords":"Lynton Crosby,Health policy,NHS,Health,Healthcare industry,Society,Public services policy,Lobbying,Conservatives,David Cameron,Politics,UK news,Business,Politics",
   "msapplication-TileColor":"#004983",
   "msapplication-TileImage":"http://static.guim.co.uk/static/a314d63c616d4a06f5ec28ab4fa878a11a692a2a/common/images/favicons/windows_tile_144_b.png",
   "news_keywords":"Lynton Crosby,Health policy,NHS,Health,Healthcare industry,Society,Public services policy,Lobbying,Conservatives,David Cameron,Politics,UK news,Business,Politics",
   "og:description":"Exclusive: Firm he founded, Crosby Textor, advised private healthcare providers how to exploit NHS \u0027failings\u0027",
   "og:image":"https://static-secure.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pixies/2013/7/21/1374433351329/Lynton-Crosby-008.jpg",
   "og:site_name":"the Guardian",
   "og:title":"Tory strategist Lynton Crosby in new lobbying row",
   "og:type":"article",
   "og:url":"http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "resourceName":"tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "title":"Tory strategist Lynton Crosby in new lobbying row | Politics | The Guardian",
   "twitter:app:id:googleplay":"com.guardian",
   "twitter:app:id:iphone":409128287,
   "twitter:app:name:googleplay":"The Guardian",
   "twitter:app:name:iphone":"The Guardian",
   "twitter:app:url:googleplay":"guardian://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2013/jul/21/tory-strategist-lynton-crosby-lobbying",
   "twitter:card":"summary_large_image",
   "twitter:site":"@guardian"
}
```

Comment: shared or basic hosting   doesn't support Java on their servers :)

Answer (score 3):

My solution *(adapted from parts of cronoklee's & shamittomar's posts)* so I can call it from anywhere and get a JSON return. Can be easily parsed into any content.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

if (!empty($_GET['url']))
{
    file_get_contents_curl($_GET['url']);
}
else
{
    echo "No Valid URL Provided.";
}


function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo json_encode(getSiteOG($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}

function getSiteOG( $OGdata){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($OGdata);
    $res['title'] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $m){
        $tag = $m->getAttribute('name') ?: $m->getAttribute('property');
        if(in_array($tag,['description','keywords']) || strpos($tag,'og:')===0) $res[str_replace('og:','',$tag)] = utf8_decode($m->getAttribute('content'));

    }

    return $res;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get meta tags from url, php function example:

```
function get_meta_tags ($url){
         $html = load_content ($url,false,"");
         print_r ($html);
         preg_match_all ("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/", $html["content"], $title);
         preg_match_all ("/<meta name=\"description\" content=\"(.*)\"\/>/i", $html["content"], $description);
         preg_match_all ("/<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"(.*)\"\/>/i", $html["content"], $keywords);
         $res["content"] = @array("title" => $title[1][0], "descritpion" => $description[1][0], "keywords" =>  $keywords[1][0]);
         $res["msg"] = $html["msg"];
         return $res;
}
```

Example:

```
print_r (get_meta_tags ("bing.com") );
```

[Get Meta Tags php](http://alex-kurilov.blogspot.com/2012/09/get-meta-tags-php.html)

Comment: Don't forget that the `name` and `content` attributes may be in different order.

Comment: Also don't forget single quotes could be used instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Easy and php's in-built function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with PHP, check out the Pear packages at [pear.php.net](http://pear.php.net) and see if you find anything useful to you. I've used the RSS packages effectively and it saves a lot of time, provided you can follow how they implement their code via their examples.

Specifically take a look at [Sax 3](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_HTMLSax3/) and see if it will work for your needs. Sax 3 is no longer updated but it might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already said, this can handle the problem:

```
$url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site/4640613';
$meta=get_meta_tags($url);
echo $title=$meta['title'];

//php - Get Title and Meta Tags of External site - Stack Overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

// ------------------------------------------------------ 

function curl_get_contents($url) {

    $timeout = 5; 
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'; 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 

    return $data; 
}

// ------------------------------------------------------ 

function fetch_meta_tags($url) { 

    $html = curl_get_contents($url); 
    $mdata = array(); 

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $titlenode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title'); 
    $title = $titlenode->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metanodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
    foreach($metanodes as $node) { 
    $key = $node->getAttribute('name'); 
    $val = $node->getAttribute('content'); 
    if (!empty($key)) { $mdata[$key] = $val; } 
    }

    $res = array($url, $title, $mdata); 

    return $res;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------ 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this small composer package based on the top answer: https://github.com/diversen/get-meta-tags

```
composer require diversen/get-meta-tags
```

And then:

```
use diversen\meta;

$m = new meta();

// Simple usage, get's title, description, and keywords by default
$ary = $m->getMeta('https://github.com/diversen/get-meta-tags');
print_r($ary);

// With more params
$ary = $m->getMeta('https://github.com/diversen/get-meta-tags', array ('description' ,'keywords'), $timeout = 10);
print_r($ary);
```

It requires CURL and DOMDocument, as the top answer - and is built in the way, but has option for setting curl timeout (and for getting all kind of meta tags).

Comment: BTW: It is considered good (and common) practice to name classes starting with capital letter, so `class meta ..` should be `class Meta....`. You may want to follow widely adopted pattern here too

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski You are right. Best practice and all that. Bad habit .)

Answer (score 1):

Now a days, most of the sites add meta tags to their sites providing information about their site or any particular article page. Such as news or blog sites.

I have created a Meta API which gives you required meta data ac like OpenGraph, Schema.Org, etc.

Check it out - https://api.sakiv.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working a different way and thought I'd share it. Less code than others and found it [here](https://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/get-remote-web-page-info-with-php). I've added a few things to make it load the page meta that you are on instead of a certain page. I wanted this to copy the default page title and description into the og tags automatically.

For some reason though, **whatever way (different scripts) I tried, the page loads super slow *online* but *instant on wamp*. Not sure why** so I'm probably going with a switch case since the site is not huge.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://sitename.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');

$content = "";

while(!feof($fp)) {
    $buffer = trim(fgets($fp, 4096));
    $content .= $buffer;
}

$start = '<title>';
$end = '<\/title>';

preg_match("/$start(.*)$end/s", $content, $match);
$title = $match[1];

$metatagarray = get_meta_tags($url);
$description = $metatagarray["description"];

echo "<div><strong>Title:</strong> $title</div>";
echo "<div><strong>Description:</strong> $description</div>";
?>
```

and in the HTML header

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Improved answer from @shamittomar above to get the meta tags (or the specified one from html source)

Can be improved further... the difference from php's default get_meta_tags is that it works even when there is unicode string

```
function getMetaTags($html, $name = null)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    try {
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    $data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);

        if (!empty($meta->getAttribute('name'))) {
            // will ignore repeating meta tags !!
            $data[$meta->getAttribute('name')] = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
    }

    if (!empty($name)) {
        return !empty($data[$name]) ? $data[$name] : false;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP simple DOM HTML Class two line code to get page META details.

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
$meat_description = $html->find('head meta[name=description]', 0)->content;
$meat_keywords = $html->find('head meta[name=keywords]', 0)->content;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it succinctly, and handle bad HTML / invalid URLs, this is what I use.

```
@if(substr(get_headers('https://www.google.com/')[0], 9, 3) == 200)
{
    @$title = preg_replace('/.*<title>(.*)<\/title>.*|.*/si', '\1',file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/'),1);
    @$desc = get_meta_tags('https://www.google.com/')['description']??'';
}
```