# Get Title and Meta Tags of any site in any language with PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-parsing, meta-tags

I want to try figure out how to get the title and all meta tags from a webpage

> ```
> <title>A common title</title>
> <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords blabla" />
> <meta name="description" content="This is the description" />
> ```

This question seem to be asked and answered several times on stackoverflow but no answer cares about the language/charset of the webpage. For example, the script of shamittomar here [Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site) only works for webpage in utf-8. This script fails to work, for ex it will return weird result for these sites:

http://www.tudou.com/

http://svmpbt.com/

(note: above websites are not mine but just examples)

Is there any way to do it in the right way, is there any available class to do this? Because Facebook Linter works correctly with above sites, I think there is available solution in PHP script.

Thanks.

Comment: `http://www.tudou.com/` is an example of a site that's not that nice, setting no charset in it's header. Manually parse the charset out from the start, and you'll be fine though. I have _no_ problems with `http://svmpbt.com/`? `iconv` may be your friend.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What should I change in shamittomar's script?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "get_meta_tags" function of php, it provides title, desscription and keyword.  for it, refer this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php
And if you need more information, then you can use "file_get_contents" method also, that will return you source of that url, then parse it and extract the relevant information.  Refer this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php