# Google API | URL to site title

Tags: php, javascript, html, url, title

For example to get the favicon of a site I can use
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=
and fill in the domain.  Google returns the favicon.
I would also like to pull the title.

I know that I could parse the title from the html on the server side...or
I could use javascript document.title on the client side.
But I don't want to have to download the whole site.

I used the favicon example b.c. it was a good example of how you have data about a site available on the web with out having to do any "heavy lifting"

There must be a similar for the title.  Essentially I want to match a URL to title.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can grab the favicon yourself by accessing it directly at www.whatevertheURLis.com/favicon.ico. I think the Google favicon tool was meant more for conversion. It outputs a png which can be used in img tags.

Comment: Yeah, but there's far more heavy lifting in converting an image than there is in parsing text, right? So I doubt there was ever a pressing need for them to make a similar service available for HTML tags.

Anyway, if you want you can write code that simply grabs an HTML document without trying to grab the content it references. That's really pretty simple and you wouldn't be grabbing "the whole site", just the text of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the Google custom search API to get the title of a website. Just search for "info:siteurl" and grab the title of the first request. I don't know exactly what you want to do, but it allows for 100 requests a day.

See details of the API here:
http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html

Comment: You just need the url and the parameters. Make sure you get an API key and you're set.

Comment: The link that @Overv posted has become https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Answer (score 1):

This post has a very nice piece of code which fetches the URL, description and keywords...

[Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site)

You do have to download the whole pages source, but its only one page and using the PHP DOMDocument class is very efficient.

You don't have to load the whole page to get a favicon because its a separate file but titles are stored inside the page source.

Comment: Well if there was a service, they would still have to download the whole page, there is no way around it really. And it would be heavily cached. Its easy to do so might as well do it yourself with a cache you can control.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=605681

I think you are looking for something like this

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But I don't think there is another way, because the title isn't send with the header. But maybe have a look at  http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=info:stackoverflow.com

Comment: You can just get the header with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php but the title isn't part of the Header. Some people discussed in get_meta_tags() how to get the title and could only solve it by downloading the whole site.

Comment: Overv gave you a link to the Google API, this is at the moment the only solution without downloading the whole site. This would be your correct element: items[].title The title of the search result, in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

#### With Google Search API

1. Create an API key here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#api_key
2. Create a "Programmable Search Engine" from here: https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/ You can restrict it to a specific domain in these settings if desired.
3. Run a `GET` request with this URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${searchAPIKey}&cx=${searchID}&q=${url}`

- `searchAPIKey` comes from step 1
- `searchID` comes from step 2
- `url` is the search text, putting a url will usually put that result first in the results. However, newer or hidden links won't show up in these results.

In the JSON response, you can get the title of the first result with `items[0].title`

#### Javascript Fetch Example with Async/Await

```
const searchAPIKey = ''
const searchID = ''

fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${searchAPIKey}&cx=${searchID}&q=${url}`).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('title:', data.items[0].title)
}
```