# extracting values from meta tags and img url having only url of website. Written in python for django app

Tags: python, django, meta-tags

I'm wondering how to write this in python and connect it to django app. I mean extracting values from meta tags and img url having only url of website. The same as facebook do when user is pasting the link.

[Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would choose to tackle this with the very nice [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), and [LXML](http://lxml.de/) libraries.

Assuming we have the following model in `models.py`, we could override the `save()` method to populate the `title`, `description`, and `keywords` attributes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from django.db import models

class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    keywords = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.url and not (self.title or self.keywords or self.description):
            # optionally, use 'html' instead of 'lxml' if you don't have lxml installed
            soup = BeatifulSoup(requests.get(self.url).content, "lxml")
            self.title = soup.title.string
            meta = soup.find_all('meta')
            for tag in meta:
                if 'name' in tag.attrs and tag.attrs['name'].lower() in ['description', 'keywords']:
                    setattr(self, tag.attrs['name'].lower(), tag.attrs['content'])

        super(Link, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The logic from the overridden `save()` method could very well live in a view or utility function or even in another method on the `Link` model that could be called conditionally.

The above works with Django 1.4. No guarantees, but it should work on earlier versions as well.

Edit: Fix syntax error and mention alternative parser, thanks [@jinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846193/jinesh) and [@stonefury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2286754/stonefury).

Comment: requests.get(self.url).contents won't work. use requests.get(self.url).content instead. also I had to use soup = BeatifulSoup(requests.get(self.url).contents, "html")

Answer (score 2):

The answer by jnovinger basically works for me in Django 1.5, but I had to make a few adjustments. First, there seems to be a typo in the code itself. The line

```
soup = BeatifulSoup(requests.get(self.url).contents, "lxml")
```

raised `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'contents'`. Based on the Requests documentation, I believe the correct attribute is `requests.get(self.url).content`, although `requests.get().text` also seems to work.

I tried implementing this in a simple script first before putting it in my Django project, and in this case I also obtained the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'www.example.com/': No schema supplied
```

This was due to naively not including `http://` before the url. In Django this is done automatically, but I mention this in case another beginner makes the same mistake and doesn't understand what is meant by 'missing schema.'

The final problem I encountered was due to lack of validation of content length. When the inspected link yielded title, keyword or details fields that were longer than the limits of the Field objects in the model (the max_length argument), this caused DatabaseErrors when trying to save new Links.

```
DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(20)
```

Here is my rough fix; there may be better approaches but this seems to work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from django.db import models

class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    keywords = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.url and not (self.title or self.keywords or self.description):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(self.url).content, "lxml")
            limit = self._meta.get_field('title').max_length    # check field max_length
            self.title = soup.title.string[:limit]              # limit title to max_length
            meta = soup.find_all('meta')
            for tag in meta:
                if 'name' in tag.attrs and tag.attrs['name'].lower() in ['description', 'keywords']:
                    field = tag.attrs['name'].lower()                   # check whether description or keywords
                    limit = self._meta.get_field(field).max_length      # check field max_length
                    content = tag.attrs['content'][:limit]              # limit field to max_length
                    setattr(self, tag.attrs['name'].lower(), content)

        super(Link, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that this will simply cut off titles, descriptions, and keyword lists mid-word rather than stopping at the last completed word, so you may end up with nonsensical word fragments.