# Adding in a function with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

How can I add in the getTitleText() function so that the anchor text displays the page title using the URL that the regular expression has found?

```
function getTitleText($Url){
 $str = file_get_contents($Url);
   if(strlen($str)>0){
     preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    return $title[1];
  }
}

$comment = preg_replace('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/', '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="$0">$0</a>',$comment);
```

Comment: Please give me an alternative solution?

Comment: Parse HTML with [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: This provides a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site

Comment: @Jake It reminds me of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1174378): "The <center> cannot hold it is too late."