# JSP Get Title and Meta Tags of External site - Stack Overflow

Tags: jsp, title, meta-tags

I want to try figure out how to get the website Title and Metadata from a link

I have seen the solution for PHP ([Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site)), however I will like to know if there is a solution for **JSP**.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.net.HttpURLConnection or [http components](http://hc.apache.org/) to get the string of the external site. Use regex or [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to extract title and metadata.