# Server side script or function to process a URL

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, web

You'll have to excuse the title and other terminology mistakes in this question.

I would like to have a function somewhere on my server that accepts a url (from a domain I don't own), retrieves the html for that url, parses it (extracting elements by id, classname, etc), and return the extracted data. For simplicity, let's say it will accept a URL and return the title of the webpage. My page will need to both provide the url to the function, and display the returned value.

What technologies should I be looking into to achieve this (and is it possible)? Is this something people would use php for?

Update - 
I am looking for an overview of the architecture as much as anything else. What kind of file(s) to I put on my server? How do I send in a URL to the php (or other file) and receive back some data?

Comment: Just about any scripting language can do this. Have a look here for a php implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site

Answer (score 2):

[`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) + [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) will be your friends.

Comment: Thats helpful but I have no idea where to use these and how to structure things - I've updated my question to be a bit more explicit.