# Get external page title from url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Code:

```
<input type="text" id="url_value"/>
<input type="button" id="get_title" value="Get title"/><br/>

<span class="url_title"></span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AdNgZ/

Is there a way to put any url on the text input, get the page title and show it on the span without going to that page?

Example:
If I put the url of this page: [Get external page title from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640344/get-external-page-title-from-url), I get the page title: php - Get external page title from url

Comment: It's called `cURL` my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site

Comment: JS cannot directly reach out to external sites to retrieve content. That's a violation of the same origin security policy. You can, however, have your server fetch the page title and send it over to the JS via ajax.

Comment: You forgot **- Stack Overflow** there.

Comment: @chriz, thank you! And sorry for repost =/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents($_REQUEST["url"]);
$title = preg_replace('/<title>(.*)</title>/i', '$1', $page);
echo htmlentities($title);
?>
```

With this code you need to activate `allow_url_fopen` php.ini directive.

**WARNING**: try to make a list of secure website and allow to get title only in their pages, to avoid XXS attacks.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/best-way-to-sanitize-user-input-in-php