# Getting Open Meta Graph Tags

Tags: php

I want to echo open meta graph from provided url.

Meta tags I want are og:title og:description. And I want to echo their content. I've come to know the following code to grab meta tags using preg_match. But can't get it work with echo and multiple meta tags.

The output I need is:

```
<h2>title goes here<h2>
<p>description of my vimeo videos is here....</p>
```

PHP Code:

```
$a = get_meta_tags('http://vimeo.com/58806905');
var_dump($a);
preg_match_all('/<meta property="og:title" content="(.*?)" \/>/', $source, $matches);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Title and Meta Tags of External site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site)

Comment: I searched but couldn't find. Thanks for providing solution.