# How to parse/get meta description/keywords from DOM?

Tags: php, dom, meta-tags

I need to parse meta description and meta keywords from the DOM using PHP. 
I used the following code to get meta description and keywords from the DOM

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);    
$tags['description'];
$tags['keywords'];
```

The above code is working fine for the following cases

```
<meta name="description" content="description goes here" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords1, keywords2" />
```

But fails in the following case

```
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keywords1, keywords1" />
<meta http-equiv="description" content="description goes here" />
```

It seems there is a way to achieve this using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser' but I would like to achieve this without using that (as this is the only requirement for my project).

Is there any way to get it work in both conditions?

Comment: Using http-equiv for keywords or description is just erroneous so don't expect any meta-tag parser to handle this.

Comment: Thanks @Capsule . ok, but there are couple of sites following the same syntax and I need to get them for my project. So is there any way to achieve this? may be using regular expressions?

Comment: `http-equiv` means to say that the value could have been passed via response headers, i.e. `Description: ...` ... but those aren't part of the HTTP spec at all.

Comment: Thanks @Ja͢ck . yes I agree. but client wants to get those anyway. :( what should I do.

Comment: You could use DOMDocument which ships with most PHP installations.

Comment: Thanks @Ja͢ck, I'll try that one. If you have time, please give me any hints.that would be more helpful for me.

Comment: btw phpQuery is very good at this, I really can't repeat it enough

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the documentation](http://php.net/get_meta_tags), "*Only meta tags with name attributes will be parsed.*".

You could potentially hack around this by copying the target page to a temporary file and modifying the page text before passing the temporary file to the `get_meta_tags()` function instead.
This is likely fragile though, and could be unpredictable in the instance that a page has both a meta tag that uses `name` and one that uses `http-equiv` with the same value.

Comment: So, you're saying that there is no straight way to achieve this?