# Getting title and meta tags from external website using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to extract title and meta tags from a webpage:

```
<title>A common title</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="sample keyword" />
<meta name="description" content="This is the description" />
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website) and it's for PHP.

How do it using AngularJS?

I've no idea at all since I'm new to AngularJS.

Comment: You can't connect to arbitrary web sites using JavaScript running in the browser, for security reasons. So you'll need to do that at server side.

Comment: @JBNizet If I do it in PHP first, how to pass the data to Angular controller? Any idea? Could you please share some examples?

Comment: Data is data is data. You'd pass such data as any other kind of data: the controller sends an HTTP request to your server, and the server responds with JSON containing data. The documentation has plenty of examples, a tutorial, etc.