# copy(..): failed to open stream: No such file or directory php

Tags: php, localhost, server

I'm trying to copy image from a given URL using PHP. I used code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711554/5026766). I added some extra codes to get the image.

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $imgurl = $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
$localimgurl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/blog/';
if (substr($imgurl, 0, 7) == "http://") {
    $serverimgurl = $imgurl;
}
elseif (substr($imgurl, 0, 8) == "https://") {
    $serverimgurl = $imgurl;
}
else {
    $serverimgurl = $url.$imgurl;
}
copy($serverimgurl, $localimgurl);
```

By executing this whole code the **$imgurl** will contain the last image in the given URL. I want to copy this image to my server. But by using the copy() function the code returns the following error. If the given URL is http://www.google.co.in

> Warning: copy(www.google.co.in/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory

I'm executing this code on my local server. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what did you not understand by **No such file or directory** if you want to save a *foreign* by http you need the **URI**

Comment: i did not understand what you meant?

Comment: it looks like the url doesn't contain http so php isn't detecting that it's a url

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure that there is no space in name. you can try using trim function. was struggling for the same and solved with trim.

copy trim($tmp_name),$destination);