# get_meta_tags http request failed 403 forbidden

Tags: php

When I do:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://example.com');
```

I get error: http request failed 403 forbidden, but when I go to site with browser all ok, status code: 200. May be I need set `user_agent`? But how I can do it?

Comment: You can try and configure the general [`user_agent`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) option (and hope get_meta_tags takes that into account.)

Comment: I don't think thats the best way to get tags from an external url. Instead, try this solution -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website

Comment: use valid url for it

Comment: are you trying to pull meta tags from general websites? You cant pull facebook's meta tags using this method

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by cURL. Here's the example:

```
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://example.com);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user agent and retrieve the meta information

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
$meta_tags = get_meta_tags('www.example.com');
```

it will return an array of all meta tags.

For more information please refer to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php)

Comment: May be will be better use guzzle for get meta tags?