# PHP - Curl and get meta tags function

Tags: php, curl, meta-tags

I want to get some meta tags from another site (both mine).

I am using curl and get_meta_tags.

My php function:

```
    $url = 'https://www.example.com';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $tags = get_meta_tags($response);
```

And I get this error:

> failed to open stream: Invalid argument in metatags\Controller\GetMetatagsController->getMetatags() (line 46 of modules\custom\mmetatags\src\Controller\GetMetatagsController.php).

(This path is from my drupal module, the module is working fine, it's only my php function is not working)

Is there anything I am missing?

I want to get open graph metatags, like og:title, og:text and so on.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website)

Answer (score 2):

If you see the php manual for [get_meta_tags](https://www.php.net/get_meta_tags) then you'd see it takes file-name as parameter instead of html response. So you could try

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');
```

Also, there is a [separate SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website) that shows how to parse the meta tags using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).