# Can't get website meta description over tor network using PHP

Tags: php, tor, darknet, onion-architecture

Dear friends I'm trying make a interesting project that we can enter a tor .onion address and find the website title and meta description related to it. So here is my code,

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init('http://torchdeedp3i2jigzjdmfpn5ttjhthh5wbmda2rr3jvqjg5p77c54dqd.onion');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE      => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME,
    CURLOPT_PROXY          => '127.0.0.1:9150',
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => '',
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($response === false) {
    echo sprintf(
        "Request failed.  Error (%d) - %s\n",
        curl_errno($ch),
        curl_error($ch)
    );
    exit;
}

if (preg_match('/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i', $response, $match)) {
    echo "The title is '{$match[1]}'";
} else {
    echo "Did not find title in page.";
}

echo "<br></br><br>";

$tags = get_meta_tags($response);
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual

 ?>
```

Actually i got the title of the website correctly. But my problem arise when i'm going to get the meta description of the .onion website. Here is a screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wWfi.png)

please help me. What is wrong with my php code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/getting-title-and-meta-tags-from-external-website)

Comment: no it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use DOMDocument to do the data parsing (I've tested in my server and it works):

Please replace:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($response);
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
```

by

```
//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($response);

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if(strtolower($meta->getAttribute('name')) == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if(strtolower($meta->getAttribute('name')) == 'keywords')
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}

echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";
```

Comment: thank you so much! This really worked! You are a god damn life saver!

Comment: Great to know that the problem is solved. Have a nice day and happy coding.